# Why is JS FS is making a new line at the end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, output, txt

I have some code that generates some text by pulling things out of files and then sending it to output.txt. However, the last two asterisks seem to be set to a new line despite nothing telling it to.

Here is the code:
`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 140);

    let s = fs.readFileSync('towns.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n')[l]
    let [a, b] = s.split('-')

    b = b.toUpperCase();

    

/* require('dotenv').config()
const { Client, Discord, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { Console } = require('console');
const client = new Client({
    intents: 3661
});

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

client.on("ready", () => {
    // Code goes here
    console.log("Bot is ready!")
})

client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === "!campaign") {
        console.log("found msg")
        msg.reply(":LNP_Logo: Campaigns in " + a + ", " + b + "")
        msg.react("✅")
    }
    })
  */  
for(let i=0; i < 1; i++) {
    var campaignOut = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt', {
        flags: 'a'
    })

    let l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 140);

    let s = fs.readFileSync('towns.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n')[l]
    let [a, b] = s.split('-')

    const campaign = [];

    for(let ii=0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() *4) + 5; i++) {
        let c = Math.floor(Math.random() *28);
        let c2 = fs.readFileSync('campaigns.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n')[c]

        campaign.push(c2)
    }

    campaignOut.write(":LNP_Logo: **Campaigns in " + a + ", " + b.toUpperCase() + "**" + "\n" + "");
    for (let iii=0; i < campaign.length; i++) {
        campaignOut.write("\n" + campaign[iii] + "\n");
    }
}
```

`

And here is the output file:
`

```
:LNP_Logo: **Campaigns in Wodonga, HUME
**
```

`

As you can see the two asterisks are on a new line.

Comment: `campaignOut.write("\n" + campaign[iii] + "\n");` seems like a good answer.

Comment: Tip: Don't forget [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) exist.

Comment: What is `iii` doing in the loop when you're incrementing `i`? `iii` never moves. I think you're tripping over your own iterator variables here.

Comment: In `towns.txt`, is there only `\n` or `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

Error solved, thankyou Louys Patrice Bessette.

Using b = b.slice(0, -1); I can remove the enter that was at the end of towns.txt.